# Compiling Spring program

Tags: spring

Currently I am learning spring framework so that I am very new to it. I wrote my following code in Notepad++

```
package com.mikadosolutions.training.spring.di;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class LaunchTraining    
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("TrainingConfig.xml");
        Workshop trainingWorkshop = (Workshop) context.getBean("trainingWorkshop");
        trainingWorkshop.conductWorkshop();
    }
}
```

Now the issue is when I am compiling it in cmd, I get package does not exist errors for both `org.springframework.context` and `org.springframework.context.support`. What are the required components and how do I compile it? I have jdk1.7 installed in my system. Please help.

Comment: How you compile it?

Comment: I am compiling it from windows cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have jar dependencies for Spring Framework. It is easiest to start new spring project using https://start.spring.io/. It will generate for you Maven or Gradle project with all required dependencies.

For more details start with one of Spring Guides from https://spring.io/guides

https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/ is good start because it has very small java program and explains well how to use Gradle.